# Play dual movies, using two sound devices one for original version and the other one for dubbed

Tags: sound, video, alsa, vlc, video-player

I have some movies, in avi and mp4 format, with two sound channels.

It would be great, if I could play both channels on different sound cards to be listened with earphones (one for me and the other one for my girlfriend).

I've seen external USB sound cards.

But I have never seen any movie players that allow this feature.

Is it possible on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Install **pavucontrol** from this [link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) using Software Center.

Next Start two instances of vlc for the same video file, use the following cmd:

```
`vlc /path/to/video.avi & vlc /path/to/video.avi`
```

Start **pavucontrol** in a new terminal using the following cmd:

```
pavucontrol
```

Now in the playback tab, scroll down to find two vlc applications. Simply change the audio output for one of the player.

[image]

Set one of the player in full screen mode and minimize the second player.

Comment: If pulse audio will not do this you will have to try jack

Comment: I'm not very sure if this solution allows me to pause, play, forward or rewind the movie.  Because VLC instances aren't synchronized, isn't true?

Comment: Both the instances start together, but thier controls are not locked together- not in sync... I'll check if we can send commands to both the instances simultaneously